# refresh table in page when hitting the save button without refreshing the whole page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i have the following code where the user enters the data and once he clicks on the save button, the table shown is reloaded where the new record if inserted into database is displayed.the table reads the data from the database. and im using ajax to load the data and save the record. here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Info</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src='jquery1.js'></script>
 <script src='jqueryTest.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Contact Information</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name" >
<span class="error">* </span>
<br><br>
Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="email" >
<span class="error">* </span>
<br><br>
Telephone:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="telephone" >
<span class="error">* </span>
<br><br>
UserName: <input type="text" id="username">
<span class="error">*</span>
<br><br>
Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" id="password">
<span class="error">*</span>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" >
<div id="validate"></div>
<?php 
 //connect to the database
  $user=$_POST["user"];
  $pass=$_POST["pass"];
  $host=$_POST["host"];
  $connector = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)
      or die("Unable to connect");
  $selected = mysql_select_db("mysql", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");

  //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ");
  ?>
<table border="2" style= "background-color: #99ffcc; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;">
<thead>
  <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
          {
           echo "<tr>
                 <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['telephone']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['username']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['password']}</td>
                 </tr>\n";
           }
        ?>
     </tbody>    
   </tr>
```

this is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//save button listener  
$("#save").click(function(){
//receiving data entered by user from design.php        
     var name = $('#name').val();
     var email = $('#email').val();
     var telephone = $('#telephone').val();
     var username = $('#username').val();
     var password = $('#password').val(); 

$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: 'contactData.php',             
   data:{"name":name,"telephone":telephone,"email":email, "username":username,   "password":password},
  // dataType:'json',
   success: function(data) {
       var result = JSON.parse(data);
       $("#validate").html(result.msg);   
                           }        
  });//end of ajax
     });//end of listener
        });//end of javascript
```

and my php code is as follows:

```
<?php 

//connect to the database
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("mysql",$con) or die(mysql_error());

 $notTaken=false;//variable to check if the username is taken or not
 $username=$_POST["username"];

//to check if username is available in the database
$query = "SELECT username FROM users"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
//to check if it is the first record  
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users", $con);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);

   if($num_rows==0)
   {
    //if there are still no records don't do anything for now, once out of the if will go to   validty()
  }
    else{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    if( $username == $row['username'])
      {
         $takenMsg='{"msg":"Username Taken"}' ;
         echo $takenMsg;
         $exitMSG='{"msg":"Try Another Username"}';
         exit($exitMSG);
       }
    else{
         $notTaken=true;
         }
    }
  }
// after checking if the usernname exists or not check for field valdation
validity();


//check for valididty
function validity(){
//variables obtained by ajax
$name=$_POST["name"];
$telephone=$_POST["telephone"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
//check if phone is all digits
$pattern_phone = "|^[0-9\+][0-9\s+\-]*$|i";
//check if email is in the right form(example@example.com)
$pattern_email="/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/";


//validate if fields are empty
if (($name == "") || ($email == "") || ($telephone == "") || ($username == "") || ($password == "")) 
{
    $errorMsg = '{"msg":"some input is missing"}';
    echo $errorMsg;      
 } 
  //validate if email is in the right form     
  elseif (!preg_match($pattern_email, $email)) 
   {
    $errorMsg = '{"msg":"email format is incorrect"}';
       echo $errorMsg;     
   } 
   //validtae if the telephone is all digits    
   elseif (!preg_match($pattern_phone, $telephone))
   {
   $errorMsg = '{"msg":"telephone should be all digits"}';
   echo $errorMsg;      
   }
 //if all fields aquire the correct validation, insert record to database

   else
  {
    $query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(name,telephone,email,username,password)  values('$name','$telephone','$email','$username','$password') ");
   //if record inserted successfully display msg indicating so
   if($query1)
    {
       $msg='{"msg":"Your info has been sent"}';
       echo $msg;
    }
//if record not inserted sucessfully display msg indicating so       
  else
    {
       $msg='{"msg":"Error in sending your info"}';
       echo $msg;
    }
}
}//end of function validity()
```

when pressing the save button if all fields are correct its saving in the database but the record is not shown at the end of the table so i want when clicking the save and the record is saved in the database the table should be reloaded and the new record will be shown as well

Answer (score 0):

Put your table in `<div></div>` and assign with id and name, after the user clicked the save button data send to database and generate the new html table with reload the data and ajax response data back to `<div></div>` been assigned.

Tips : Ajax can response back html code and do display in `<div></div>`

Comment: can you plz help by updating the code.im new to ajax